# Plot do predict para modelo Gamlss ajustado

Tags: r, plot

Como faço para fazer e plotar o `predict` para este modelo Gamlss ajustado?

Meu modelo está apresentado abaixo.

```
mod<- gamlss(cbind(nfr, nv-nfr)~tt+tr1+d2+d3+random(as.factor(p ))+random(as.factor(id))+random(as.factor(no)), 
        data=ta, family = "BI")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o exemplo do [livro](https://www.amazon.com.br/Flexible-Regression-Smoothing-Using-GAMLSS/dp/1138197904) "Flexible Regression and Smoothing Using GAMLSS in R", o plot dos valores preditos, ajustados, pode ser feito seguindo o exemplo abaixo.

```
library(gamlss)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(film90)

# plot das observacoes
plot(lborev1~lboopen, data = film90, col = "lightblue")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
model <- gamlss(lborev1~pb(lboopen), data = film90, family = NO)

# plot das observacoes + valores ajustados
plot(lborev1~lboopen, col = "lightgreen", data = film90)
lines(fitted(model)[order(film90$lboopen)]~
        film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)], col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
film90 <- film90 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(lb2 = lboopen^2,
                lb3 = lboopen^3)
model2 <- gamlss(lborev1~lboopen + lb2 + lb3, data=film90, family=NO)

plot(lborev1~lboopen, col = "lightgreen", data = film90)
lines(fitted(model2)[order(film90$lboopen)]~
        film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)], col = "grey10", lwd = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
{
  plot(lborev1~lboopen, col = "lightgreen", data = film90)
  lines(fitted(model)[order(film90$lboopen)]~
          film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)], col = "red", lwd = 2)
  lines(fitted(model2)[order(film90$lboopen)]~
          film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)], col = "grey10", lwd = 2)
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também é possível plotar utilizando o `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot2::ggplot(film90) +
  geom_point(aes(x = lboopen, y = lborev1), col = "lightgreen", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)],
                y = fitted(model)[order(film90$lboopen)]), col = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(x = film90$lboopen[order(film90$lboopen)],
                y = fitted(model2)[order(film90$lboopen)]), col = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(4, 20),
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como seu exemplo não é totalmente reproduzível, adaptei um pouco este do livro. Mas acredito que você não terá problemas para adaptar ao seu caso.

```
term.plot(model2, pages = 1, partial = T)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Maiores exemplos de emprego do `term.plot()` podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Etaconeli/CE04320/Ex1p2.pdf) ou [aqui](https://www.gamlss.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Practicals-Bilbao.pdf)..

Comment: Fica a seu critério. Pode depender da quantidade de modelos que vc tem e do "dataviz", para seu gráfico não ficar poluído.

Comment: De nd! Vou editar e colocar mais elementos gráficos. Se puder aceitar a resposta, agradeço.

Comment: Coloquei a informação a mais